# Using Google Sheets API from Java using GKE Workload Identity

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-kubernetes-engine, google-sheets-api, workload-identity

We've been successfully using the Java client for Google Sheets for a while within our GKE cluster, using the `ComputeCredential` class to provide credentials. The following code is more or less what we're doing:

```java
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.compute.ComputeCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;

NetHttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
ComputeCredential credential = new ComputeCredential(transport, jsonFactory);
Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("myApplication")
                .build();
```

We've recently enabled Workload Identity on our cluster and this integration no longer works—we get a 403 with the message `ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT`. I think this is because the default scope encompasses Google Cloud APIs and doesn't allow you to specify the Google Sheets scopes that are needed.

I've found the `ComputeEngineCredentials` class in [google-auth-library-oauth2-http](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/main/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/oauth2/ComputeEngineCredentials.java) which allows passing in scopes but isn't compatible with the Google Sheets library.

I've raised [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/issues/2030) but there's been no reply as yet.

Does anyone know how to use the Google Sheets library with Workload Identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution to this! For anyone else wondering, you can edit the token server URL on the ComputeCredential object to include the scopes, like this:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.compute.ComputeCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;

NetHttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
ComputeCredential.Builder builder = new ComputeCredential.Builder(transport, jsonFactory);
GenericUrl url = builder.getTokenServerUrl().clone().set("scopes", "<your scopes here>");

ComputeCredential credential = builder.setTokenServerUrl(url).build();

Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("myApplication")
        .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

The oAuth2 flow requires user interaction - use a service account for the server-side.

Comment: Getting credentials from the metadata API (which is what we've been doing by using the `ComputeCredential` class) _is_ the way you get service account credentials but you still need a set of scopes to get the access token.